# When can a test in Google Test Framework fail?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a test for Google Test Framework that is failing without any further explanation, meaning that the test suite is not crashing but is correcly ending its execution printing:

```
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
```

with the name of the failed test.

The question is: when can a test in Google Test Framework fail?
I only know about missing `EXPECT_CALL` and wrong `ASSERT_TRUE`/`ASSERT_FALSE`, but they all should provide a better explanation in the standard output.

Is there anything else that can make a test fail?

Comment: How about unexpected exception thrown?

Comment: @VTT furtunately, I can exclude this case because our code doesn't use exceptions at all, due to OS restrictions.

Comment: But google test code does use them anyway.

Comment: In **above** report, you should have detail of each test.

Comment: @Jarod42 I have it. I mean, the report is correctly listing the failing test, but is not telling me the reason why the test is failing. Since I know both EXPECT_CALL and ASSERT are more verbose than what I'm getting in the output, my question is: can a test fail also for other reasons?

Comment: @VTT do you mean that I should run the `RUN_ALL_TESTS` macro inside a `try`-`catch` block and print out everything that is catched?

Comment: I think you should just debug failing test and figure out what exactly fails.

Comment: Please produce a [mcve]. It's possible to do all kinds of things in GoogleTest, including extending the framework, that could lead to this sort of behavior. Otherwise we cannot tell you.

Answer (score 0):

A test can also fail if an `EXPECT_CALL` macro is completely missing for a mocked function if the mocked class is wrapped with the `StrictMock<>` template class and that function is going to be called in during the test execution.